# Insert Not Working After CardNo Update in PHP Zkteco

Tags: php, biometrics, zkteco

I am working with my biometric Zkteco using PHP languange I am using the following repository https://github.com/vodvud/php_zklib to create connected application into it. But I got some error in inserting user or copying data from biometrics A to B,C, etc..

I am using the following code below:

```
<?php
include('zklib/ZKLib.php');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila'); //Default Timezone
$users = [];
//Main device
$zk = new ZKLib('192.168.5.166');
$ret = $zk->connect();
if ($ret) {
    $zk->disableDevice();
    //Get users
    $users = $zk->getUser();
    $zk->enableDevice();
}
$zk->disconnect();


if (count($users) > 0) {
    //Sync devices list
    echo (count($users));

    $devices = [
        '192.168.5.167',
        '192.168.5.163'
    ];

    foreach ($devices as $ip) {

        $zk = new ZKLib($ip);
        //$zk = new ZKLib('192.168.5.167');
        $ret = $zk->connect();
        if ($ret) {
            $zk->disableDevice();

            //Remove old users
            $zk->clearUsers();

            foreach ($users as $user) {
                //Add user
                $zk->setUser(
                    $user['uid'],
                    $user['userid'],
                    $user['name'],
                    $user['password'],
                    $user['role'],
                    $user['cardno']
                );
            }
            $zk->enableDevice();
        }
        $zk->disconnect();
    }

    $zk->setTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
}
```

I try the following code but some insert but not in their position some no data sync.

No data display to other device
A. sample 1

```
$zk->setUser(
    $user['uid'],
    $user['userid'],
    $user['name'],                   
    $user['cardno'],
    $user['role'],
    $user['password']
);
```

B. sample 2

```
$zk->setUser(
    $user['uid'], 
    $user['userid'],
    $user['name'],  
    $user['password'],  
    $user['role'],             
    $user['cardno']
);
```

The data copy but not in proper position

```
$zk->setUser(
    $user['userid'],
    $user['name'],  
    $user['cardno'],
    $user['uid'],   
    $user['role'],             
    $user['password']
);
```

I already create issue: https://github.com/vodvud/php_zklib/issues/19 
My repo: https://github.com/aice09/php_zklib-1/blob/master/sync.php

Comment: did you figure it out ?

Comment: yes please visit https://github.com/vodvud/php_zklib, the card number issue is already fix @ChiKaLiO

Comment: yes i was using another lib.. but is there a way to insert fingerid ?

Comment: What library did you use?

Comment: the one by vovud, https://github.com/vodvud/php_zklib he said:      * TODO: Still can not set fingerprint. Need more documentation about it...
 i have zk9500 and i'm lost :p

Comment: I thought card number? But you talking about inserting fingerprint. I know that library still cannot insert fingerprint and looking for docs also.

Comment: yeah :c you have any news ? the only way available is in c# i guess

Comment: @ChiKaLiO, I don't have any news about it. and I also looking for reference until now.

Comment: i'm doing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65312153/call-c-sharp-program-from-javascript i'll keep you posted