# Call c# program from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, localhost, windows-services

i need to call c# from javascript, i'm new to c# so i can't figure out where to start..

this is my javascript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">             //Default.aspx
   function runCsharp() {     
         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '..../csharp',  //here i'm lost
         data: "",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (msg) {
             alert('it works');
         },
         error: function (e) {
             alert('something went wrong');
         }
     });
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Unless you also install a local webserver on the machine then JavaScript cannot be used to access the C# program (and even then the program would need to be within an asp.net environment.). For security reasons browser's cannot directly execute any program on the machine where the browser is running. Can you imagine the chaos that would happen with hackers etc. if it was possible?

Comment: So...maybe rethink whether an angular app is really the best program to use for this scanning process. Perhaps a desktop application would be more suitable.

Comment: @ADyson or.. Electron?

Comment: @ADyson: you don't even need a web server, a desktop app with a localhost socket listening on 12345 is a perfect cors target from a browser app.

Comment: @CaiusJard you could...but if there's already C# code for the scanner (which there seems to be, from the question) then why not just build a fully C# application?

Comment: @WiktorZychla but the socket still needs to speak HTTP for a browser to be able to talk to it, as far as I know?

Comment: @ADyson I was kinda thinking the angular app is the bigger thing that already exists and the finger scanner is a new addition to it..

Comment: @ADyson: yes, of course.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Well a program that listens on a port and understands HTTP is by definition a webserver then, surely? Even if it's a very simple one. I don't really see a difference between your suggestion and mine. I didn't specify that a full-blown IIS install had to happen, or anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create Windows Service, that will host simple Web Server that will process 'http' requests from angular app.
.Net core has a Kestrel server that can be used for this and for your use-case it will be quite enough.
Don't forget to turn CORS policy on.

Comment: Is that service able to access the fingerprint scanner?

Comment: I'm trying this solution i'll mark it as solution right after i figure out owin.. thanks

Comment: Dunno if I'd bother with OWIN, probably easier if you have a block of C# already, to just chuck it in a project along with an Unosquare EmbedIO web server and expose a json endpoint for your javascript to hit

Comment: @CaiusJard yup that's what i'm doing i created console app listenning on port 9000 then i will convert it so windows service